# HTTP API Authentification in R via 0auth

Tags: r, api

I got some problems accessing tracking API via 0auth;

I have sign key, secret and Authorization_key.

Sign key and secret should form a sig file as I understand and authorization_key that should be added as header.

The code:

```
auth_info <-
  read.csv2('./Data/auth_info.csv',
            encoding = 'UTF-8',
            stringsAsFactors = F)

express <-
  oauth_app("express", key = 'Ur1475', secret = auth_info$sign_key)

sig <- sign_oauth1.0(express)

order <-
  GET(
    "http://www.express.ru/api/v2/getOrder?orderNumber=WEBN3141018",
    authenticate("Ur1475", auth_info$sign_key),
    add_headers(Authorization = auth_info$auth_key),
    sig
  )

order_info <- content(order)

order_info
```

Returns me auth error;

Official api documentation tells that should be formed md5(client key . URL  . GET params . POST params . sign key).

Also I've looked at 0auth function code it does not use http. 
Could it cause the problem?

Could you please comment on how to get data from API via R?

API doc (in russian)): https://www.express.ru/docs/APIExpressRu.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The major of API's (Google, Twitter, Facebook) need a token that you must to obtain from an oauth authentication. Depending from the API's you must to use the functions `GET`or `POST`. And you must to provide your key encoded in `base64`. So what I think you need is:

## First: Authenticate.

```
if(!require("jsonlite")){library("jsonlite")}
if(!require("httr")){library("httr")}


#Create your own appication key
consumer_key <- "your consumer key" #needed
consumer_secret <- "your consumer secret" #some api's don't need.

#Use basic auth
secret <- jsonlite::base64_enc(paste(consumer_key, consumer_secret, sep = ":"))
req <- httr::POST("https://url.of.your.api/oauth/token", #"oauth" and "token" are not parameters, they are fixed.
                  httr::add_headers(
                    "Authorization" = paste("Basic", gsub("\n", "", secret)),
                    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
                  ),
                  body = "grant_type=client_credentials"
)

#Extract the access token
token <- paste("Bearer", httr::content(req)$access_token)
```

## Next: Make a request.

```
url<-"http://url.of.your.api/search?parameter1=value&parameter2=value"

req <- httr::POST(url, httr::add_headers("Authorization" = token))

json <- httr::content(req)
json
```

As I said, some API's need `GET`and others `POST`, try both.

Comment: I am sure that API does not provide tokens.
Here is their SDK for PHP https://github.com/ExpressRu/SDK/blob/master/src/Api/Auth/SignatureGenerator.php

What does this mean: "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: All in all, I still don't underatand where I should place signature key

Comment: "Content-Type" is related with the codification, As I said, I am not sure if your API is equal to my code, but the major of API's work similar, is only a general code, because the documentation that you shared is in russian :S. 

Try to adapt the code to your API, if you provide me a documentation in English, may be I help you.

The API's don't provide tokens, the token must be extracted by you, doing the above.

Comment: In your code, you putted `secret = auth_info$sign_key`. Must be in the CSV that you read previously.

Comment: Documentation tells in fact that sig should be formed as md5(username . URL.GET params.POST params . signaturekey); and after that I only should add auth_key as header

Comment: I don't understand how to complete the first stage

Comment: What is the URL of your API? So, put the URL I say `"https://url.of.your.api/oauth/token"`

Comment: You must to have a `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`, this last depend on the API, for example, Google doesn't need.